# Android Studio 3.0.1 unknown element <user-permission> found

Tags: android, xml

Ok, I was making a project that will use my localhost to test out a username and password from an app. I am getting an error message for AndroidManifest.xml. It says:

> error: unknown element [user-permission] found.
>   unknown element [user-permission] found.

Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
Failed to execute aapt

What could possibly be the problem?

Here is AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android=... >

<uses-sdk
    ... />

<user-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    ... >
    <activity android:name="com.example.application.mysqldemo.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        ... />
    <meta-data
        ... />

    <provider
        ... />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Also, I am using Xampp as my localhost and also I am using port 8080, instead of port 80 due to firewall issue on apache. So, will I be able to access a file like this?:

```
String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/login.php";
```

Comment: <uses-feature> elements belong outside of the <application> tags, as direct children of <manifest>. Same for <uses-permission> elements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

There is no such element. Most likely, you want `<uses-permission>`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

> So, will I be able to access a file like this?: localhost:8080/login.php

No, assuming that `localhost` is your development machine. Your development machine is not your Android device, nor is it your Android emulator. For a device, or for an emulator running on some other computer, you will need the actual IP address of your development machine. If you are using the Android emulator on the same machine as this Web server, replace `localhost` with `10.0.2.2`, as is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html).

Comment: I tried <uses-permission> code how you said and it changes it back to <user-permission>

Comment: @AlexH: Most likely, [you are accidentally editing the wrong manifest file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/04/08/why-cant-edit-manifest-android-studio.html), courtesy of some stupid behavior on Android Studio's part. Make sure that you edit the *real* manifest, not whatever pops up in a tab in the IDE.

Comment: Sorry I was still editing, that is not what I meant to say. I updated it again. I am using port 8080 on apache, so I will use 10.0.2.2:8080 correct?

Comment: @AlexH: If you are running your app in an emulator running on the development machine that has that Web server, then yes, `10.0.2.2:8080` is right address and port.

Comment: Ok, that make sense, I was in the debug/AndroidManifest.xml file. It works now, thanks.